# Installing pygame for python3 in mac using anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pygame, anaconda

I am trying to install pygame for python 3 and get the error:
conda install -c cogsci pygame
Solving environment: failed

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in 
conflict:
  - pygame
  - xlwt
 Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Tried to install xlwt again but nothing change :

```
conda install xlwt
Solving environment: 
done 
All requested packages already installed.
```

Any idea how to install it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `UnsatisfiableError` means that the two packages listed cannot be installed in the same environment. You need to create a new environment to install pygame:

```
conda create -n pygameenv -c cogsci pygame
```