# How to install django cms in Anaconda/Conda?

Tags: python, django, anaconda, conda, django-cms

When I try to install Django cms in conda with `conda install -c auto djangocms-installer` I get the following error message:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>     - anaconda==5.2.0=py36_3
>     - djangocms-installer

How to install django cms in Anaconda/Conda?

Comment: That seems pretty self-explanatory... `django` conflicts with `anaconda`. You either have to uninstall `anaconda` or create a new environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing pygame for python3 in mac using anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972603/installing-pygame-for-python3-in-mac-using-anaconda)